# Closed form of parametric integral

Tags: integration

I'm looking for a closed form for the parametric integral
$f(a) = \int_0^1 (ax + b)^k dx$.
If $a\neq 0$, $f(a)$ is a rational function
$$f(a) = \frac{(a+b)^{k+1} - b^{k+1}}{a(k+1)}$$
which reduces to a $k$-degree polynomial
$$\frac{1}{k+1} \sum \left(k+1 \atop i\right) a^{k-i} b^i.$$
The value of this polynomial at $a=0$ is the same as $f(0)$,
so $f$ is just this polynomial;
but a $k$-degree polynomial isn't in closed form
($k$ is indeterminate).

Is there a better way to find a value for $f$?
In a general parametric integral
$$f(a) = \int_0^1 g(a,x) dx$$
there seems to always be a problem at values of $a$
where $g(a,x)$ is constant in $x$,
which forces a special-case at these points,
even when an antiderivative $G$ is known:
$$f(a) = \begin{cases}
g(a,0) & \text{if } \displaystyle{\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}}
(a,x) = 0 \\
G(a,1) - G(a,0) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
Is there a general way to find the closed form of these functions?

Comment: There shouldn't be any $x$ in a closed form for  $f(a)$.

Comment: It should be: $$f(a)=\frac{(a+b)^{k+1}-b^{k+1}}{(k+1)a}$$

Comment: In general, you can't find a closed form for most integrals, regardless if they're from a (relatively simple seeming) parametrized family or not. This integral is a trivial $u$-substitution, and is in its closed form.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the function's closed form? As I said, I can't get it further than a $k$-degree polynomial, but $k$ is indeterminate.